# What's wrong with this code to find index of list of integers where sum of integers to the left equals the sum to the left?

Tags: python, iteration, slice

I am going to be given an array of integers. My job is to take that array and find an index N where the sum of the integers to the left of N is equal to the sum of the integers to the right of N. If there is no index that would make this happen, return -1.

My code is:

```py
def find_even_index(arr):
    #your code here
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if sum(arr[0:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:len(arr)]):
            return i
        else:
            return -1
```

This code works for some lists, but doesn't work for others. What's wrong here? E.g. it doesn't work for [14, -6, -1, -8, 8, 16, 4, -10, -11, -10, 2, 8, 4, 14, -8, -10, 21, -10, -1] it should return 12 but returns -1, likewise for a lot of other lists where it should return an index but returns -1.

Comment: Should it be ignoring the item at index `N`?

Comment: @EdwardPeters yes it should

Answer (score 0):

So `return` returns from the function the moment it's run. You're doing the check and returning one thing or another every time - so if the *first* element doesn't evenly divide, you immediately return -1.

You need to only return false if you go through the entire list without finding a valid `N`.

After you fix that you'll get an index out of bounds error on lists with no valid `N`. When you reach the last element of `range(len(arr))`, you'll try to take a slice that starts at `len(arr)`, which is out of bounds.

Also this might be intentional, but remember that slice indices are inclusive on the left and exclusive on the right - so your code is not including the element *at* index `i` in either slice.

Finally this is a slow implementation - you're re-doing the sums for every element of the list, which will be `O(n^2)`. It would be faster to take the left and right sums once at the start (left will be 0), then subtract from the right and add to the left as you traverse each element.

Comment: Right, got you. So I set a variable ans to "", and set ans to i if the if statement is true, and set it to -1 in else, and ask to return answer after exitting the for loop, but I still get a similar error, it returns -1 when it should return an index position.

Comment: Several things: First, edit those changes into your answer rather than just describing them. Second, you should get out of the habit of re-assigning variables between different types. I think it's bad that Python even *lets* you do that, but it's definitely bad practice. Third, that will run into a similar problem - you're assigning `i` every loop iteration. So if you find the index towards the middle, you'll keep going and overwrite it with `-1` further down the list.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with @Edward Peters comment about the last return statement being after the for loop runs, and I also thought there might be a out of index error for the case where the list doesn't have an answer satisfying the results, I didn't find that to be the case here is the code I used.

```
t1 = [14, -6, -1, -8, 8, 16, 4, -10, -11, -10, 2, 8, 4, 14, -8, -10, 21, -10, -1] 
t2 = [1, 3, 5, 2] 

def find_even_index(arr):
    #your code here
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if sum(arr[0:i]) == sum(arr[i+1:len(arr)]):
            return i
    return -1
```

then:
`find_even_index(t1)` yields 12
`find_even_index(t2)` yields -1